# ScrollViewer in a listbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I´m filling a listbox with a specific data, the code works fine, but I need to add a scrollviewer to the listbox because there are many elements inside, I tried to use a ScrolViewer and put inside the listbox, but doesn't work, here is the code

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Sites" Grid.Row="1"  Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListBox x:Name="ListSites" >
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Button Width="460" Height="120" Click="click" Name="btn">
             <Button.Content>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="100" Width="460">
                <TextBlock Width="460" Name="txtname" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding name}" Height="40" Foreground="CadetBlue" />
                <TextBlock Width="460" Name="txtUrl" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Url}" Height="60"/>
               </StackPanel>
              </Button.Content>
              </Button>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ListBox is not given infinite space for height then it should automatically scroll when items overflow its boundaries. For instance, if the second Grid row outside your stackpanel has explicit or 'star' height set, the scrollbar in the listbox will show up automatically.

See also: [Silverlight: Difficulty with ScrollViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004270/silverlight-difficulty-with-scrollviewer)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, simply adding the Height property in the ListBox control

Comment: The solution you've posted is no different to that proposed by other experts - can I ask why you didn't choose one of their answers?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to add a `ScrollViewer` to your `ListBox`. It will start scrolling when it runs out of room.

However, because you've put the `ListBox` inside a `StackPanel` it won't ever think it's run out of room because the `StackPanel` grows infinitely in the direction of it's orientation to accommodate its contents.

You'll need to use a different container for your `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```